# MySQL, MariaDB: How do I create a child-parent hierarchical recursive query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM paper ORDER BY id DESC) paper_sorted,
        (SELECT @pv := 26) initialisation
        WHERE find_in_set(id, @pv)
        AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', last_id))
        ORDER BY @pv ASC LIMIT 0,15
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e2df/24

This works perfectly fine in MySQL; however, I am working with a MariaDB database and this query is not working.  Anyway to rewrite this for it to work for both MySQL and MariaDB?

Database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE paper (
    id INT,
    last_id INT
);

INSERT INTO paper VALUES (19, 0);
INSERT INTO paper VALUES (20, 19);
INSERT INTO paper VALUES (21, 20);
INSERT INTO paper VALUES (22, 21);
INSERT INTO paper VALUES (23, 19);
INSERT INTO paper VALUES (24, 23);
INSERT INTO paper VALUES (25, 23);
INSERT INTO paper VALUES (26, 24);
```

MariaDB v. 10.3.18;
MySQL v. 5.7.27

This SQL query should get all the Parent IDs. 
As in the example query, `@pv` variable is 26, and thus gets 26->24->23->19.

However, this is not working for MariaDB.  It's only returning one row, which is 26 in MariaDB.  How to rewrite this query to work for both MariaDB and MySQL?

Comment: What version of MySQL and MariaDB?

Comment: Can you say what you mean by *not working?* Error message? No rows in result set? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: This question is unclear since we don't know the database versions. Voting to close.

Comment: I will have the exact versions of the SQL DB's in a few hours.  I am currently not sure as I don't have access to them at this moment. Will reply to this thread once updated.

Comment: MariaDB v. 10.3.18;  MySQL v. 5.7.27

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to rewrite the query as a [Recursive CTE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/). These were added into MariaDB 10.2 and allow querying hierarchical data structures with SQL.

Something along these lines should work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE p AS (
    SELECT * FROM paper WHERE id = 26
    UNION
    SELECT c.* FROM paper AS c, p WHERE p.last_id = c.id
) SELECT * FROM p ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 15;
```

---

**Edit:** If you need the SQL to be backwards compatible with older versions, you can use a stored procedure to achieve the same result.

```
DELIMITER // ;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p1(IN id_in INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT id_in;
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE results LIKE paper;

    WHILE i IS NOT NULL DO
          INSERT INTO results SELECT p.id, p.last_id FROM paper AS p WHERE p.id = i;
          SET i = (SELECT r.last_id FROM results AS r WHERE r.id = i LIMIT 1);
    END WHILE;

    SELECT * FROM results;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE results;
END;
//

DELIMITER ; //
```

Comment: Great, this works for MariaDB!  Although WITH RECURSIVE is only for MySQL v. 8+

Comment: For backwards compatibility, I think a stored procedure should work.